# Ribbon Cable Disconnected

Tags: cables

[image]
I am having trouble figuring out how to reconnect this ribbon cable*. My dear removed it when he was trying to fix our projector and cannot figure out how it went in. There doesn’t seem to be a way for it to reconnect or I am clearly missing something. Any info would be appreciated.

(*) - Actually, it's a flexible flat cable.

Comment: I would not call this a ribbon cable, it's a "flat cable". But I think ribbon cable should remain so that others can find this question from that search term.

Answer (score 9):

Slide the ribbon cable in, then you push the black plastic part of the connector in. It provides a friction lock.

Here you can see a similar connector in both open and closed states.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to **pull the lock (the brown part of the connector) out** before you insert the cable. Once the cable is inserted, push on the lock to close it, it will then hold the cable in place.